# PHP Memory Dump

Tags: php, memory-leaks

I have a long execute PHP script that executes for months , In last version I have a memory leakage and I dont know where is problem , As I have many changes in last version I cannot manually check changes

Notice that is is long execute PHP script after 10 days , I see that the script consume about 5GB RAM (the previous version just consumed 280MB RAM ) , I want to dump memory after days to see what remains in RAM forever , How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

The best way to debug your code is using [xDebug](https://xdebug.org/). You can integrate it to your favorite IDE (PhpStorm recommended) and use debugging and profiling features of it.